# Generic method for retrieving list of models (structs)

Tags: go, struct, crud

I'm trying to create basic CRUD for my service. It is based on data models created in structs. The problem is that I really dont want to repeat code for CRUD methods. For example I have ModelA and ModelB defined as structs:

```
type ModelA struct {
    ID              bson.ObjectId     `json:"ID,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Slug            string            `json:"slug" bson:"slug,omitempty"`
    Creator         string            `json:"-" bson:"creator,omitempty"`
    DefaultLanguage string            `json:"defaultLanguage" bson:"defaultLanguage,omitempty"`
}

type ModelB struct {
    ID              bson.ObjectId     `json:"ID,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Type            string            `json:"type" bson:"type,omitempty"`
}
```

What I want is to make generic method which retrieves an array of given model. It is important for me to use models. I can do it quick with pure `interface{}` types but will loose model functionality, for example hiding some properties in JSON output (ex. `ModelA.Creator`).

So far I've created generic methods for creating new data and retrieving single model. Here is example code:

```
// GET: /modelsa/{:slug}
func (r *Routes) GetModelA(w rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request) {
    // set model as ModelA
    var model models.ModelA
    r.GetBySlug(w, req, &model, "models")
}

// GET: /modelsb/{:slug}
func (r *Routes) GetModelB(w rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request) {
    // set model as ModelB
    var model models.ModelB
    r.GetBySlug(w, req, &model, "models")
}

func (r *Routes) GetBySlug(w rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request, m interface{}, collection string) {
    slug := req.PathParam("slug")

    if err := r.GetDocumentBySlug(slug, collection, m, w, req); err != nil {
        rest.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    w.WriteJson(m)
}
```

`GetModelA` and `GetModelB` are route handlers which uses generic method `GetBySlug` that returns a JSON formatted by given model.

I want to do the same but with the array of given models. So far I ve got problem to cast the result into the struct:

```
// GET /modelsa/
func (r *Routes) GetModels(w rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request) {
    // I think in this case I don't have to pass an array of struct
    // because the given struct is only reference. It could be:
    // var result models.ModelA as well. Converting it into array could 
    // be done in GetList() method
    var result []models.ModelA
    r.GetList(w, req, &result, "models")
}

func (r *Routes) GetList(w rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request, res interface{}, col string) {

}
```

I cant set `res` argument as an array of interface{}. Also I if i try to cast result to the `[]interface{}` within `GetList()` method, I cant then cast it to the `res` argument as it is not an array.

Is there a nice way to do this? Maybe I think wrong and should redesign the methods? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare new types which represent slice of your models. For example,

```
type ModelAList []ModelA
type ModelBList []ModelB
```

Then when you pass variables of these new types into your `r.GetDocumentBySlug()`, the functions in the `encoding/json` package will unmarshal the slices accordingly.

You can find working examples [here (marshaling)](https://play.golang.org/p/MRz2vLJHGp) and [here (unmarshaling)](https://play.golang.org/p/H5ODIZIdWJ).

Comment: Hmm, thats a nice idea. Didn't thought about creating new type, but how can I pass it to the `GetList` method? In my example there is res of type `interface{}`. I cant make it `[]interface{}` and also cant check for example length of the result as it is not slice or array

Comment: Ok, it is working ! I just made the `interface{}` type which holds given slice type. Removed also checking the length of slice. It cant be done this way. Probably I have to unmarshall it. Thanks for great answer !!